# How to build a dynamic grub on a usb-drive?

Tags: usb, grub2, live-usb

I would like to setup GRUB on a USB where it detects automatically the available OS installations on the machine that it is plugged into...

This could be useful if you messed up your default GRUB menu on a computer and would like to boot into the machine w/out booting Live-OS.  Or if you have multiple Live-OS installations on a USB-Drive and would like to add/remove different installations w/out needing to update grub manually.

I know that Grub2 has a OS-prober feature that looks for other installations on the hard-drive, but will that work in either of the scenarios listed above?

Answer (score 3):

Actually, someone already made this :)

[SugerGrub2Disk](http://www.supergrubdisk.org/super-grub2-disk/) is your friend.

Comment: someone should add efi-32